# Running a .NET MVC API from command line

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I want to locally run a .NET Visual Studio API project that services a front-end project for debugging. Right now I'm opening two windows of Visual Studio and running them from Visual Studio. Is there a way to run the api project from a powershell or command prompt and have it run on localhost? I know with .net core I can use `dotnet run` but this is not a .net core project.

Comment: It seems like you have two Visual Solutions solutions. Could you combine them into a single solution? If so, you can make multiple startup project, and API as `Start without debugging`.

Comment: You can also run the API project on a Local IIS server.

Comment: Im specifically looking for a command line solution